if must have both main and else branches if used as an expression
When I try to run the following, it says 'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression. I have the score variable and the result variable as shown below. What is wrong with my code below?
var score = 76
var score_letter = if (0 < score < 50 ) {
    println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf D")
} else if (51 < score =< 60) {
    println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf C+")
} else if (61 < score =< 70) {
    println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf C")
} else if (71 < score =< 85) {
    println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf B")
} else if (86 < score =< 100) {
    println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf A")
}
println(score_letter)

EDIT :
I just fixed my code, and now it looks like this. Is this correct?
var score = 101
var score_value =
    if (score <= 100) {
        if (score <= 85) {
            if (score <= 70) {
               if (score <= 60) {
                    if (score <= 50) {
                        if (score >= 0) {
                            "Skor $score mendapatkan skor huruf D"
                        } else {
                            "Skor $score dibawah 0"
                        }
                    } else {
                       "Skor $score mendapatkan skor huruf C+"
                    }
                } else {
                    "Skor $score mendapatkan skor huruf C"
                }
            } else {
                "Skor $score mendapatkan skor huruf B"
            }
        } else {
            "Skor $score mendapatkan skor huruf A"
        }
    } else {
        "Tidak dapat ditentukan"
    }

println("The Result : $score_value")

It's a bit different from the if-else in Python and VBA macro Excel. For example, if-else in Python
if (condition1):
   Do Something
elif (condition2):
   Do Something
elif (condition3):
   Do Something
else:
   Do Something

and if-else in VBA Excel
if condition1 then
   do something
elseif condition2 then
   do something
elseif condition3 then
   do something
else
   do something
end if


An expression must always complete in some way. When score is <= 0 or >= 100, then there's nothing for it to return or throw. So you use an if as an expression, then you must add some else { ... } at the end of the chain.

No, your edit is not correct. Just add a single else { ... } to your original code which will handle the case if your score <= 0 or score > 100 . Because this is the missing case, the compiler is complaining about. Then it will work the same way as your pyhton or VBA examples ...

There are multiple issues with your code, but you are on the right track. About your main issue: You are using ifas an expression. You do that if you have a conditional expression, and you want to assign the result of that to a variable. In your case, though, you are printing to standard out with println which does not return anything (Unit). Therefore, assigning it to a variable makes no sense in the first place and your println(score_letter)makes no sense as well. It would therefore probably be better if you did something like this (the code won't compile yet, but step by step):
var score = 76
var score_letter = if (0 < score < 50) {
    "D"
} else if (51 < score =< 60) {
    "C+"
} else if (61 < score =< 70) {
    "C"
} else if (71 < score =< 85) {
    "B"
} else if (86 < score =< 100) {
    "A"
}
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $score_letter")

This already looks better, but apart from the other syntax errors, the compiler has no way of knowing the allowable range of score. From its point of view, it could take any positive or negative integer value. In your code, the behavior for score < 0 and score > 100 is undefined (as well as for some other values of score, see below), causing the compiler to throw a compiler error. The next step would therefore be to define an out-of-range-behavior, e.g., like so:
var score = 76
var score_letter = if (0 < score < 50) {
    "D"
} else if (51 < score =< 60) {
    "C+"
} else if (61 < score =< 70) {
    "C"
} else if (71 < score =< 85) {
    "B"
} else if (86 < score =< 100) {
    "A"
} else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
}
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $score_letter")

Lastly, the syntax for range checks and number comparisons looks a little different in kotlin. From more verbose to more concise, you could write your code like so:
var score = 76
var score_letter = if (0 < score && score < 50) {
    "D"
} else if (51 < score && score <= 60) {
    "C+"
} else if (61 < score && score <= 70) {
    "C"
} else if (71 < score && score <= 85) {
    "B"
} else if (86 < score && score <= 100) {
    "A"
} else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
}
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $score_letter")

Replacing the number comparisons with range checks:
var score = 76
var score_letter = if (score in 1..49) {
    "D"
} else if (score in 52..60) {
    "C+"
} else if (score in 62..70) {
    "C"
} else if (score in 72..85) {
    "B"
} else if (score in 87..100) {
    "A"
} else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
}
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $score_letter")

Replacing the if with when:
val score = 76
val scoreLetter =
    when (score) {
        in 1..49 -> {
            "D" // 1 <= score <= 49
        }

        in 52..60 -> {
            "C+" // 52 <= score <= 60
        }

        in 62..70 -> {
            "C" // 62 <= score <= 70
        }

        in 72..85 -> {
            "B" // 72 <= score <= 85
        }

        in 87..100 -> {
            "A" // 87 <= score <= 100
        }

        else -> {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
        }
    }
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $scoreLetter")

Removing all unnecessary parenthesis:
var score = 76
var score_letter =
    when (score) {
        in 1..49 -> "D" // 1 <= score <= 49
        in 52..60 -> "C+" // 52 <= score <= 60
        in 62..70 -> "C" // 62 <= score <= 70
        in 72..85 -> "B" // 72 <= score <= 85
        in 87..100 -> "A" // 87 <= score <= 100
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
    }
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $score_letter")

Lastly, the kotlin style guide advises using val wherever possible and var only if there's no other option. The difference is that vals are immutable (i.e. the assigned value cannot be changed after the fact) whereas var is mutable (i.e. the assigned value could change at anytime). Furthermore, the kotlin naming conventions follow the Java naming conventions for the most part, which use camelCase for local variables, making your code look like so:
val score = 76
val scoreLetter =
    when (score) {
        in 1..49 -> "D" // 1 <= score <= 49
        in 52..60 -> "C+" // 52 <= score <= 60
        in 62..70 -> "C" // 62 <= score <= 70
        in 72..85 -> "B" // 72 <= score <= 85
        in 87..100 -> "A" // 87 <= score <= 100
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("score $score is out of range")
    }
println("nilai $score memiliki nilai huruf $scoreLetter")

Also, if you look at the number ranges, you might find that your code never defined a behavior for score == 50, 51, 61, 71 or 86.

Thank you very much for the explanation, really helpful for beginners like me. Sorry for my bad English and thank you the revision hehe. Can I ask you one more? "Also, if you look at the number ranges, you might find that your code never defined a behavior for score == 50, 51, 61, 71 or 86." Yes, I noticed that, why is it like that?

In your question, you specified if (0 < score < 50 ) { /* ... */} else if (51 < score =< 60) and 50 is not smaller than 50 and smaller than 51. You should have used 0 < score <= 50  instead. Alternatively, you could adjust the ranges in my answer to 1..50, 51..60 and so on.

Since you're comparing your solution to other languages: Instead of chaining if, else-if, else-if, (...), else in most cases it's more readable to use a when expression, especially when you have a subject to use. You can even use ranges for each case:
val msg = when(score) {
    0 -> "you have not scored anything"
    in 1..50 -> "your score is worth a D"
    in 51..60 -> "your score is worth a C+"
    // other ranges up to 100
    else -> "unexpected score above 100"
}
println(msg)


Note that else case must exist because this when() is an expression and a value must be returned. It will also happen when score < 0 but assuming it's not a valid score it's not included in the message.
